# Selects between values for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table X:

```
id      startDt     EndDt
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1/1/1900    9/30/2012
2       10/2/2012   10/4/2012
3       10/3/2012   10/7/2012
4       11/5/2012   11/15/2012
```

I need to write a query that selects all rows from ANOTHER table, Y, where EventDate is between each start and end date from X.

That is, the result set should be a union of all records in Y where the date is between the start and end dates for  each row.  (all dates between 1/1/1900 and 9/30/12 + all dates between 10/2/2012 and 10/7/2012 + all dates between 11/5/12 and 11/15/12)

I do have a working procedure doing this, but the solution is using a loop and I'd like to do it in a  query if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

for dates that are between at least 1 start and end date

```
select * from y t1
where exists (
    select 1 from x t2 where
    t1.eventdate between t2.startDt and t2.endDt 
)
```

in case you only want dates that are between every start and end

```
select * from y t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from x t2 where
    t1.eventdate not between t2.startDt and t2.endDt 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

FuzzyTree's answer is likely the fastest and best, but figured I'd share an alternative.  Perhaps the only advantage is readability.

```
Select *
From Y y1
Where 
    (Select Count(*) From x) =
        (  Select Count(*) 
           From x1
           Where y1.date Between x1.StartDate And x1.EndDate
        )
```